# ingress configuration for dashboard

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, dashboard, docker-ingress

I did nginx ingress controller tutorial from [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) and
exposed kubernetes dashboard

```
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.233.53.77    <none>        443:31925/TCP   20d
```

created ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.org/ssl-backends: "kubernetes-dashboard"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - serverdnsname
    secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
  rules:
  - host: serverdnsname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
```

---

```
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx          NodePort    10.233.21.200   <none>        80:30827/TCP,443:32536/TCP   5h
```

https://serverdnsname:32536/dashboard
but dashboard throws error

```
2018/01/18 14:42:51 http: TLS handshake error from ipWhichEndsWith.77:52686: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

and ingress controller logs

```
2018/01/18 14:42:51 [error] 864#864: *37 upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.233.82.1, server: serverdnsname, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://ipWhichEndsWith.249:8443/dashboard", host: "serverdnsname:32536"
10.233.82.1 - [10.233.82.1] - - [18/Jan/2018:14:42:51 +0000] "GET /dashboard HTTP/2.0" 009 7 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36 OPR/49.0.2725.64" 25 0.001 [kube-system-kubernetes-dashboard-443] ipWhichEndsWith.249:8443 7 0.001 200
```

On my mind it is related with nginx redirection to upstream: "http://ipWhichEndsWith.249:8443/dashboard" .
tried to update controller image version to 0.9.0-beta.19 - didnt help

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As you pointed out, looks like nginx is proxying your https request to `ipWhichEndsWith.249:8443`, which is an HTTPS endpoint, using `http` as protocol.

You should add the following annotation to your PodSpec:

> **LATEST**
>
> This annotation was added to replace the deprecated annotation since 0.18.0
>
> [#2871](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/2871) Add support for AJP protocol

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

---

> **DEPRECATED**
>
> This annotation was deprecated in 0.18.0 and removed after the release of
>   0.20.0
>
> [#3203](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/3203) Remove annotations grpc-backend and secure-backend already deprecated

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
```

---

This should make nginx forward your request to the pods with https.

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#backend-protocol

Docs: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol

Comment: You sir are a true hero.

Comment: For those who come here late, this one is changed to:
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`.
I think k8s really need to provide a changelog

Answer (score 5):

Just for code reference. There are 2 gtochas. Setting the proper annotations since the dashboard talks https and using the correct namepace for the ingress. tls config is optional.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-google
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - kube.mydomain.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: kube.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
            servicePort: 443
```

Answer (score 5):

To keep this ticket updated (if user uses nginx ingress) in order to reach the Kubernetes Dashboard you need to apply the following annotations:

```sh
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

Do not use `secure-backends` on later versions than `image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.26.1`. It is replaced by `backend-protocol`.

If the user is using ingress in non https port e.g. 80 can be done as documented here [TLS termination](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/) (nging ingress documentation).

Sample of complete code with subdomain:

```sh
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      kind: Ingress
      metadata:
        name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
        namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
        annotations:
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
      spec:
        tls:
        - hosts:
            - "dashboard.my.example.com"
          secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-secret
        rules:
        - host: "dashboard.my.example.com"
          http:
            paths:
            - path: /
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: kubernetes-dashboard
                  port:
                    number: 443
```

Hope this help other beginners like me not to spend so much time to figure out how to do it. Also the user should take in consideration the external load balancer configuration towards the ingress controller. Remember to set it up as `SSL Pass-Through` for the port that you will be forwarding.

**Update:** In case the user wants to use another ingress provider e.g. [Kubernetes Ingress Controller Documentation/HAProxy Kubernetes Ingress/Controller 1.4](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes/latest/installation/)

Sample of code with annotations:

```sh
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      kind: Ingress
      metadata:
        name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
        namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
        annotations:
          haproxy.org/server-ssl: "true"
      spec:
        tls:
        - hosts:
            - "dashboard.my.example.com"
          secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-secret
        rules:
          - host: "dashboard.my.example.com"
            http:
              paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: kubernetes-dashboard
                    port:
                      number: 443
```

The user should not forget that the secrets are unique per namespace.

Comment: haproxy.org/sever-ssl: "true" just saved the day for me

Comment: this one helped!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the helm charts available here

[helm-chart/kubernetes-dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/aio/deploy/helm-chart/kubernetes-dashboard)

Then setup your `values.yaml` file in order to override `ingress` parts like enable it, and adding hosts are available.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ingress for the dashboard that works for me.

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      namespace: kube-system
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          rewrite ^(/dashboard)$ $1/ redirect;
    spec:
      ingressClassName: nginx
      tls:
      - hosts:
        - yourdomain.com
        secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-tls
      rules:
      - host: yourdomain.com
        http:
            paths:
              - path: /dashboard(/|$)(.*)
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: kubernetes-dashboard
                    port:
                      number: 443
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall be fixed at deployments itself by setting the SERVER_BASEPATH and SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH, redirection at ingress level will be smooth,

**Deployment file**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: osd-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: osd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: osd
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: osd
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          image: 
          env:
            - name: server.ssl.enabled
              value: "false"
            - name: OPENSEARCH_HOSTS
              value: http://opensearch-service:9200
            - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
              value: /dashboard
            - name: SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH
              value: "true"              
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5601
              name: http
```

**Service File:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: osd-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: osd
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: port5601
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5601
      targetPort: 5601
```

**Ingress file:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: osd-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 128k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"  
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: osd-service
            port:
              number: 5601
```