# Accessing the Kube dashboard on IBM Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, containers, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-dashboard

The kube dashboard should be easily accessible from the IBM Cloud console.

However when I try accessing it, I get a 401 error message (this is not always the case however it happened a lot today)

[image: Dashboard access 401 error]

The suggestion provided in the 401 page did not help.

Answer (score 2):

There was an IBM Cloud incident that affected IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service management functions, including kube dashboard access. This issue has been resolved.

The outage is posted here: https://console.bluemix.net/status/notification/877c340fb941bc8c72211c513763c077

Answer (score 1):

The source of this information is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above). And [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control) you can find the information about access tokens for Kubernetes dashboard.

Check if you are still able to connect to Kubernetes dashboard in the following ways:

**kubectl proxy**:

Check if your kubectl is properly configured and has access to the cluster.

```
`$ kubectl cluster-info 
Kubernetes master is running at ...
...`
```

Start local proxy server:

```
$ kubectl proxy
```

Use the following address to access dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

**API Server**:

If you are able to communicate with the cluster apiserver right from your workstation, you can access the dashboard by following this link:

```
https://<master-ip>:<apiserver-port>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

The apiserver port is 6443 by default.

**Ingress**:

You can [expose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324760/ingress-configuration-for-dashboard) a dashboard port using an Ingress resource.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.org/ssl-backends: "kubernetes-dashboard"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - server-dns-name
    secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
  rules:
  - host: server-dns-name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: VAS, there is a Kubernetes Dashboard link in the IBM Containers page. It should normally work when you click on it. I can certainly try the kubectl proxy approach however I would like to keep my life simple to get the link working (and it is expected to work).

Answer (score 0):

We also have a timing issue when new clusters are created where the kubedashboard is not available immediately after cluster-create. We're working on providing better status/messaging in this window of time. Typically if you see this shortly after a cluster create, you may just need to wait a few minutes for the dashboard to be started.